# Plotting 3D Surface with Sage Math

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sage

I am trying to plot a 3D surface using [SageMath Cloud](http://cloud.sagemath.com/) but I am having some trouble because the documentation for matplotlib does not appear to be very thorough and is lacking in examples. Anyways the program I have written is to plot the Heat Equation solution that I got from analytical method.

The case is:
[Heat Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9QT1.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from sympy import *
from math import *

x = np.linspace(-8, 8, 100)
t = np.linspace(-8, 8, 100)

n = symbols('n', integer=True)
X, T = np.meshgrid(x, t)

an = float(2 / 10) * integrate(50 * sin(radians((2 * n + 1) * pi * x / 20)), (x, 0, 10))
Z = summation(an * e**(2 * n + 1 / 20)**2*pi**2*t * sin(radians((2 * n + 1) * pi * x / 20)), (n, 0, oo))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, T, Z,
                  rstride = 3,
                  cstride = 3,
                  cmap = cm.coolwarm,
                  linewidth = 0.5,
                  antialiased = True)

fig.colorbar(surf,
         shrink=0.8,
         aspect=16,
         orientation = 'vertical')

ax.view_init(elev=60, azim=50)
ax.dist=8
plt.show()
```

I am getting this error when I run the code to plot the graph: "Error in lines 7-7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/sage/sage-7.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 968, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/projects/sage/sage-7.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 93, in linspace
    dt = result_type(start, stop, float(num))
TypeError: data type not understood"

Please, any and all help is very greatly appreicated. I think the error comes up because I defined `x = np.linspace(-8, 8, 100)` and `t = np.linspace(-8, 8, 100)` but it is necessary to make the original program run. I am unsure of how to correct this so the graph plots properly. Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually using Sage itself?  Or just pure Python inside of a SageMathCloud notebook/Jupyter notebook?  If the former, switch to the latter and that might solve any namespace or preprocessing conflicts.

Comment: Just a pure Python inside it. What do you mean by switch to the latter?

Comment: I meant that if you were using Sage rather than *pure* Python, there are some built-ins or preparsing that might mess things up.  Probably the `-8` etc. are interpreted as Sage integers, which np won't understand.  Try putting `int` around all those ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your piece of code has problem with these two lines:

```
an = float(2 / 10) * integrate(50 * sin(radians((2 * n + 1) * pi * x / 20)), (x, 0, 10))
Z = summation(an * e**(2 * n + 1 / 20)**2*pi**2*t * sin(radians((2 * n + 1) * pi * x / 20)), (n, 0, oo))
```

I would suggest that you use simple for-loop to compute some other simple values for Z first to confirm that everythng is fine. Try replace the 2 lines with this:

```
# begin simple calculation for Z
# offered just for example
Z = []
y = symbols('y')  # declare symbol for integration
for ix,ea in enumerate(x):
    ans = integrate(y * sin(ea / 20), (y, 0, x[ix]))  # integrate y from y=0 to y=x(ix)
    Z.append(ans)
Z = np.array(Z, dtype=float)  # convert Z to array
# end of simple calculation for Z
```

When you run it, you should get some plot as a result. For your intended values of Z, you have better situation to compute them with simple for-loop.

[image: My result plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it and I got this error:
Error in lines 31-31
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'cos'

Comment: Sorry I use pastebin because the limitation of comment chars:
http://pastebin.com/hFNYXrba

BTW, I thank to you so much for your help.

Comment: Try put your code on Jupyter notebook on sagemathcloud.  On the first cell, use this

Comment: %matplotlib inline

Comment: Yes, it works!
I've tried your suggestion, here is my code: http://pastebin.com/BiCmtUNb

I got a problem the result. It's difference with the true result. It should be: https://s22.postimg.org/4kzl6ff1d/image.png, but mine: https://s16.postimg.org/rv5zk9ojp/image.png

Comment: That's the first step to get through and obtain graphic result. The other part is to get the correct value of Z. Write a function separately for it.

Comment: However, if someone's answer is useful, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: I'm stuck here. Last time, I got the result: https://s11.postimg.org/6lk5xrj2r/figure_1.png
My code: http://pastebin.com/tMV5wZK3

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please post the original equation that you use to compute Z value. All the details for using it is helpful. Maybe better, ask it as a new question.

Comment: Here is the original equation and its boundary conditions:   
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9QT1.jpg

Comment: The formula for An is unclear and incomplete, does it have dx or dn ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I mean it's dx.